# run another process after the background process is complete

Tags: bash, background-process

said i have looping script in file test.sh, i  just want to running script "running_script2.sh" after the background process is complete, what i try like this, but it's not working .

```
for id in 1 2 3
do
bash running_script1.sh $id &   (#complete 1 minute/looping)
done
wait
echo "running script2 ..."
bash running_script2.sh
```

its work when :

```
bash running_script1.sh 1 &
bash running_script1.sh 2 &
bash running_script1.sh 3 &
wait
echo "running script2 ..."
bash running_script2.sh
```

but its not efficient

Comment: The first line of your example, the ```for``` statement, should have the literal word ```in``` between ```id``` and the numerals.

Comment: ups, I forgot to add 'in'

Answer (score 2):

There is no semantic difference between

```
for id in 1 2 3
do
bash running_script1.sh $id &   (#complete 1 minute/looping)
done
```

and

```
bash running_script1.sh 1 &
bash running_script1.sh 2 &
bash running_script1.sh 3 &
wait
echo "running script2 ..."
bash running_script2.sh
```

This demonstration script below runs little over 3s (you can `time` it) regardless of whether the condition command is `true` or `false`:

```
#!/bin/sh -eu
for i in 1 2 3; do
    echo "sleep $i" > $i && chmod +x $i
done
if false; then
    for i in 1 2 3; do
        bash ./$i &
    done
else
    bash ./1 &
    bash ./2 &
    bash ./3 &
fi
wait
```

If you're still experiencing discrepancies, please post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether this is a right approach but I have used screen to run script
screen is a virtual terminal to run process in bg

```
for id in 1 2 3
do
screen -d -m bash script1.sh $id
done
wait
echo "running script2 ..."
bash script2.sh
```

screen -d -m will run the script and closes the screen after the script completes.
I cannot get the output of script1 in standard output while using screen so I used a file to store the output of script1.